# different component prefix for each app in nrwl nx

Tags: angular, nrwl

Is there a way for me to have a different component selector prefix for each app without tslint throwing a fit (i.e. App1 prefix 'one', App2 prefix 'two'?  You can only list one prefix in component-selector property.  I know I can just remove that from tslint.json all together but was hoping there was a different way.

Comment: Are you against using something like `app-one-component_name` and `app-two-component_name`?

Comment: I'm not against it.  They would get pretty long but that is better than having the same prefix for every app.  In my opinion that defeats the purpose of having a prefix at all

Comment: Then @pixelbits answer should work for you

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue because I forgot to set a different prefix when generating the new app project.

I changed it in `project.json`, there is `prefix` and in `.eslintrc.json` where the `prefix` is defined in the rules. This is of course only if you use ESLint, which is the default now.

Answer (score 0):

tslint has a "-c" option to specify the "tslint.json" file and a "-p" option to specify the "tsconfig.json".

Between these two options, you should be able to target folders and target a specific prefix.

Comment: would that mean I would need to copy the root tslint file that the cli creates and put one in each app?